# Change the looks of the character limit ruler

Tags: options

I wonder if there is a way to have a ruler displayed between the 80th and the 81th character in vim. I know that one can highlight the 81th column, but that actually looks as ugly as something from the DOS era. Is there a way to display a pretty ruler like the one in sublime?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately not possible in vim; painting color on anything less than a full cell is not possible for (most?) terminals. There are several other options available, such as changing changing background color for text when it overflows the 80 character limit, though.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235439/vim-80-column-layout-concerns), while being about a different issue, provides several alternatives to a normal color column.

Answer (score 1):

As @Wolfie said, there is no way to make the 81st column look pretty. Personally I color column 81 and up. This looks decent and does not distract me too much. Try it with the following statement:

```
:let &colorcolumn=join(range(81,999), ',')
```